Error while running coverage run because of os.environ in python
My code is importing several variables using os.environ. When I run 'coverage run' command for testing, it gives key error. Is there a way to provide env files to read env variables from there, or just ignoring those env variables.
This is the bash script that I am running.
#!/bin/bash
set -e
BUILD_TAG="nonprod.abc.com/$IMAGE_NAME:$BUILD_VERSION"
echo $BUILD_TAG
echo $WORKSPACE
docker run -v $WORKSPACE/tmp:/data_loader/log $BUILD_TAG \
bash -c \
'coverage run --include=/data_loader/src/* --omit=data_loader/src/groovy/* \
-m pytest --junitxml=/data_loader/log/app-pytestreports.xml && \
coverage xml --omit="data_loader/src/groovy/*" -o /data_loader/log/coverage.xml && \
coverage report --include=/data_loader/* --omit=/data_loader/src/groovy/* > /data_loader/log/coverage.txt && \
coverage html --include=/data_loader/* --omit="*/data_loader/src/groovy/*" -d /data_loader/log/app-coverage '

The command coverage rungives the following key error -
11:30:41  File "work.py", line 6, in <module>
11:30:41      logger.setLevel(os.environ['LOG_LEVEL'])
11:30:41    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
11:30:41      raise KeyError(key) from None
11:30:41  KeyError: 'LOG_LEVEL'

Any body has any suggestions?

Could you add code please to reproduce the error?

@User051209. I have added the code
